Tomcat 9 takes 1 minute to stop - workaround stops working
Tomcat takes 60s+ to shutdown and is described in details, including a workaround, here Tomcat 9 takes 1 minute to stop.
This issue exists up to the latest version of Tomcat (9.0.93). The workaround of changing the "Timeout" stops working at version 9.0.90 and above.
I believe the issue is that, according to the changelog here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html,
version 9.0.89 uses Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.4.0 64-bit) whereas version 9.0.90 and above uses Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.4.0.0 64-bit).
I don't know enough to determine if the upgrade is the cause for the workaround to stop working
(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/changes-report.html#a1.4.0) nor able to swap them to prove so (searched the machine but couldn't find it. Must be embedded somewhere).
Please help me to understand if I'm right about the above and how to proceed to get a fix.
Edit: The question is: does the upgrade from Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.4.0 64-bit) to Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.4.0.0 64-bit) cause the provided timeout to be ignored so that the default of 60s is always in effect?

You need to ask an actual question in order to get an answer.

Thank you !!! Edited to ask the question as suggested.

Apache Commons Daemon is the tomcat9.exe file.. I believe you can swap with the older version and test.. But have you found any new workaround or any insights on what is the change in timeout behavior?

A head-scratcher here: I have swapped the .89 exe for the .90 exe.  It worked.  I put it aside looking into Bootstrap, etc..  Now, it works intermittently even on the .89 machine. I've tried "..add utilityThreadsAsDaemon="true" to the Server
element in server.xml" from a mail archive for version .14, which supposedly was fix in the later version = no joy.  I've tried various Timeouts from the Tomcat9x.exe = no joy.  I've asked this same question in the Apache user mail = no fix.  So, the only thing I've left is the procrun version as shown above.
